# Cannot POST /path

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I've looked through multiple post about this but can't seem to pinpoint the problem. I'm doing a donation page for an organization and need this to check if paypal is even working. It's an error between my form and app.post. Error I get is: Cannot POST /path . Can't use / because its the path for my contact form

```
   app.get("/donate", (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + "views/donate.html"));
    app.post("/done", (req, res) => {
        const create_payment_json = {
            intent: "sale",
            payer: {
                payment_method: "paypal",
            },
            redirect_urls: {
                return_url: "https://asociacioncorazondiverso.org/donate.html",
                cancel_url: "https://asociacioncorazondiverso.org/donate.html",
            },
            transactions: [
                {
                    item_list: {
                        items: [
                            {
                                name: "Donación",
                                sku: "001",
                                price: "10.00",
                                currency: "USD",
                                quantity: 1,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    amount: {
                        currency: "USD",
                        total: "10.00",
                    },
                    description: "Donación",
                },
            ],
        };

        paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
                    if (payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
                        res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Form:

```
<div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
        <h2>Donación de 10 USD</h2>
        <form action="/done" method="post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"  value="Buy">Donación</button>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you get the form submission on to your console?

Comment: No I do not get that when I submit the form

Comment: Can you post the full code of the top snippet instead of posting half of a snippet?

Comment: I added some more won't let me post the whole code

Comment: @Sharkhan any suggestions

Comment: @Shafkhan source code from tutorial: https://github.com/gauti123456/PaypalNode.js/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I ran your app on my computer and it worked. It's redirecting to the PayPal payment page.

Comment: It's not on my mine what could be the problem? I also have my contact form info on this server.js file.

Comment: @Shafkhan Here's all my code: https://github.com/lebaneseblonde252/AsocicaionCorzonDiverso

Comment: Can you create one CRUD operation, push it to github with package.json file and share with me the link please?

Comment: Done here is the link: https://github.com/lebaneseblonde252/AsocicaionCorzonDiverso

Comment: @Shafkhan Here is the link.

Comment: In your server, you've `views/path` not `/path` but in html, you've `path`. Did you check that?

Comment: @esqew No chance that it does. You can find my code here:  github.com/lebaneseblonde252/AsocicaionCorzonDiverso

Comment: @lebaneseblonde252 In the future, please note that it's frowned upon to not include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the body of your question by linking to external sources. External links tend to break and remove most all value for future visitors to your question. Instead, edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code to better help those trying to help you. See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SagarV I've already tried that doesn't change anything.

Comment: The error "Cannot POST" usually means that the route is not defined. This is exactly the case in the code uploaded to GitHub. It looks like a mess, and it's defining the route `post "/"` inside the `post "/sendmail"` route handler.

Answer (score 2):

Your [code as you posted on GitHub](https://github.com/lebaneseblonde252/AsocicaionCorzonDiverso/blob/main/donate.html) and provided in the comments on the initial question shows a striking difference between what you posted here and what you're actually working with.

Above, your `<form>`'s `action` parameter is clearly set to `"/done"` (which appears to be correct, as that's the path you've defined in your receiving server's code).

However, the code you seem to *actually* be working with is referencing `/path` in the same `<form>` element declaration:

```
<form action="/path" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"  value="Buy">Donación</button>
</form>
```

Adjust the `action` parameter to match what you have in your question above (`"/done"`) so your HTML document `POST`s to the correct path/endpoint you've defined.

```
<form action="/done" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"  value="Buy">Donación</button>
</form>
```

Comment: they are both defined as path now but I'm still getting this error: Cannot POST /path

Comment: I am now getting an unresolved body variable in webstorm:  let textBody = `FROM: ${request.body.name} EMAIL: ${request.body.email} MESSAGE: ${request.body.message}`;
I have app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded( { extended: false } )); // this is to handle URL encoded data

Answer (score 0):

I saw syntax error in your server.js file on your [github link](https://github.com/lebaneseblonde252/AsocicaionCorzonDiverso/blob/main/donate.html) for this code

```
app.post("/", function(request, response) {
```

this part is not closed properly, otherwise your code is working if you correctly use paths.

Comment: I closed that in still getting this error when I click on my donation button: Cannot POST /path

Comment: its views/path, not only path.  **app.post(`views/path`, (req, res) =>***

Comment: I changed it. Still saying undefined path in my html file.  When I closed the tags I'm now getting an unresolved body variable I posted on stackoverflow and I have bodyparser middleware loaded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785920/unresolved-body-variable

Comment: Fixed my server now getting cannot POST views/path

Comment: Latest code pushed to github check donate.html and server.js: https://github.com/lebaneseblonde252/AsocicaionCorzonDiverso

Comment: I have made changes, please check this [link](https://github.com/salman-mustafa1230/simple-donation-app-node)

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the full api url

```
<form action="http://localhost:3030/done" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"  value="Buy">Donación</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a brackets issue in the server.js file that you've hosted on github. The post routes are defined inside the /sendmail route. Move those outside and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

Good evening what if you change you code from

```
app.post, app.get to 


const router = express.Router();

router.get('/done', (req, res) => { // do smth });

app.use('/', router);

app.use(router);
```

It should work for you. Just try ;)